# How to implement comment notification?

Tags: php, mysql

I am trying to implement notifications on comments, that is - if I comment on a post and another user comments on the same post, I'll get a notification. I've handled the notification for the post owner using this query

```
SELECT id, owner_id, post_id, user_id2, COUNT(user_id2) AS num, type, UNIX_TIMESTAMP(date_done) AS date 
FROM notification
WHERE owner_id = '$user_id' AND user_id2 != '$user_id' 
ORDER BY date_done DESC
```

[image: notification table]

In the table above, `owner_id` is the person that owns the post, the `user_id2` are those that commented on the post.

**How do I tell the user with id 17 that two persons (with user id 2 and 1) also commented on the post?**

If I should use a second table, please tell me how the structure should be. Thanks

Comment: You need something to ID the post don't you? The query you've pasted above only selects from the database by user_id.

Comment: how do you know notification is read , and to not show it again ?

Comment: @Pete, the post has a unique ID already. The query I posted isn't really the challenge now, but the query to send notification to other users that commented on the same post.

Comment: @safarov, I've thought of that but I want to get the notifications first. However, there's a remove notification link on each displayed notification, so the owner can remove the notification if they want.

Comment: @Chibuzo removing notification is not correct. For example if user 17 read notification but user 2 dont. And user 2 will never been notifed

Comment: @safarov, how do I implement it?

Answer (score 3):

The following query gets the user(s) who have commented

```
SELECT   DISTINCT user_id2 
FROM notification
WHERE post_id = '$post_id'
```

But you don't want to notify the person currently posting so...

```
SELECT   DISTINCT user_id2 
FROM notification
WHERE post_id = '$post_id'
AND user_id2 != '$user_id'
```

Or am I missing something?

Answer (score 1):

I suggest separating posts and comments into separate tables with a one to many relation

post {
  id,
  user_id,
  content,
  date
}

comment {
  id, 
  post_id, 
  user_id,
  comment,
  date
}

Then you can simply poll your comments via a timeout ajax call. If comments have been added by a user_id that's not your, inject a notification into the page.

Comment: The post and comments each has a table just as you suggested. I want other users that comments on the post to also get a notification, not only the post owner.

Comment: Sure so whenever any user is on the post page, you poll for any comments submitted for that post. And if there are any, inject a notification.

Comment: I get your point, but the situation is that I want the users to get the notifications on their user page and then a link to the post page. Thanks anyway.

Comment: So you poll for all comments on any post that user has created (or commented on).

Answer (score 0):

This class that I created will give you the detail. I have done what you need to do with the method 'notify_chain'. You will need to see the other functions, so I will post the whole class for you here.

```
<?php 


class Notification extends DatabaseObject{

public $id;
public $type;
public $post_id;
public $owner_id;
public $user_id2;
public $date_done;
public $read_or_not;
public $notifications;
public $message;
public $count;

protected static $table_name="notifier";
protected static $db_fields = array('id', 'type', 'post_id', 'owner_id', 'user_id2', 'date_done', 'read_or_not');


public function check_notification(){
    global $database;
    global $session;
    if($session->is_logged_in()) { 
    $id=$session->user_id;

    $sql = "SELECT * FROM notifier WHERE owner_id={$id} AND read_or_not = 0";
    $chk = $database->query($sql);
    if(!empty($chk)){
        while($notifs = $database->fetch_assoc($chk)){
            $message="";
        $this->notifications[]  = $notifs;
        $this->id                           = $notifs['id'];
        $this->type                         = $notifs['type'];
        $this->post_id                  = $notifs['post_id'];
        $this->owner_id                 = $notifs['owner_id'];
        $this->user_id2                 = $notifs['user_id2'];
        $this->date_done                = $notifs['date_done'];
        $this->read_or_not          = $notifs['read_or_not'];
            foreach($notifs as $notif){
                $user=Member::get_name($this->user_id2, false);
                if($this->type=="comment"){
                    $message = "<a href='post.php?post=".$this->post_id."&ntf_clr=".$this->post_id."'>".$user." commented on your post.</a>";
                } elseif($this->type=="reply"){
                    $message = "<a href='comment_reply.php?c_id=".$this->post_id."&ntf_clr=".$this->post_id."&cmt=Comment&rpl=CommentReply'>".$user." replied to your comment.</a>";
                } elseif($this->type=="discussion_comment"){
                    $message = "<a href='discussion.php?discussion=".$this->post_id."&ntf_clr=".$this->post_id."&cmt=Comment&rpl=CommentReply'>".$user." Commented on your discussion.</a>";
                } elseif($this->type=="discussion_reply"){
                    $message = "<a href='comment_reply.php?c_id=".$this->post_id."&ntf_clr=".$this->post_id."&cmt=Comment&rpl=CommentReply'>".$user." replied to your discussion comment.</a>";
                } elseif($this->type=="article_comment"){
                    $message = "<a href='article.php?article=".$this->post_id."&ntf_clr=".$this->post_id."'>".$user." Commented on your article.</a>";
                } elseif($this->type=="article_reply"){
                    $message = "<a href='comment_reply.php?c_id=".$this->post_id."&ntf_clr=".$this->post_id."&cmt=ArticleComment&rpl=ArticleCommentReply'>".$user." replied to your article comment.</a>";
                } elseif($this->type=="chain_comment"){
                    $message = "<a href='post.php?post=".$this->post_id."&ntf_clr=".$this->post_id."'>".$user." also commented to a post.</a>";
                } elseif($this->type=="chain_reply"){
                    $message = "<a href='comment_reply.php?c_id=".$this->post_id."&ntf_clr=".$this->post_id."&cmt=Comment&rpl=CommentReply'>".$user." also replied to a comment.</a>";
                } 
            }
            $this->message = $message_array[] = $message;
        } if(isset($message_array)){return $message_array;}         
        } else{
            return false;
        }
        }   
        }

        public static function mark_as_seen($notif_id){
            global $database;
            global $session;
            $me = $session->user_id;
            $sql = "UPDATE `notifier` SET read_or_not=1 WHERE owner_id = {$me} AND post_id={$notif_id}";
            $clear_notification = $database->query($sql);
        }

        public static function make_notification($post_id, $owner_id, $user_id2, $type="comment"){
            $notif = new Notification();
            $notif->type=$type;
            $notif->post_id=$post_id;
            $notif->owner_id=$owner_id;
            $notif->user_id2=$user_id2;
            $notif->date_done=strftime("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S", time());
            $notif->read_or_not=0;
                $notif->create();
        }


        public static function notif_count($id){
        global $database;
        $notif_cnt = $database->query("SELECT COUNT(*) as notifs FROM notifier WHERE owner_id={$id} AND read_or_not = 0");
        $data=$database->fetch_array($notif_cnt);
        return $data['notifs'];
        }        

        public static function notify_chain($post_id, $user_id2, $type="chain_comment"){
        global $database;
        global $session;
            $sql = "SELECT DISTINCT user_id2 ";
            $sql .= "FROM notifier ";
            $sql .= "WHERE post_id = {$post_id} ";
            $sql .= "AND user_id2 != {$session->user_id} ";
            $chain = $database->query($sql);
        while ($users = $database->fetch_assoc($chain)){
            $list = "";
            foreach ($users as $user){
                Notification::make_notification($post_id, $user, $user_id2, $type="chain_comment");
                $list = $user;
            }
            $list_array[] = $list;
        } return $list_array;

        }

}

$notif = new Notification();

?>
```

I hope that helps. check out maestrojosiah PG at facebook if you have any problems.